# How to add class in 2 sets of list items in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am facing  a problem to make even odd list with add 2 list items in php
 **here is my code:**

```
<?php
$assets = array('Bag', 'Charger', 'Power Cable', 'Video Cable', 'Mouse', 'Keyboard', 'Test', 'Test 2', 'Test 3');
?> 
<ul>
<?php 

$i=0;
foreach($assets as $category)
{ 
if($i++ %2 == 0){ 
echo '<li class="odd">' . $category . '</a></li>';
} 
else{ 
echo '<li>' . $category . '</a></li>';
}

}

?>
</ul>
</div>
```

** this is printing like

```
<ul>
    <li class="odd">item1 </li>
    <li>item2 </li> 
    <li class="odd">item3 </li>
    <li>item4 </li> 
    <li class="odd">item5 </li> 
    <li>item6 </li>
</ul>
```

BUT i need the result like

```
<ul>
    <li class="odd">item1 </li>
    <li class="odd">item2 </li>
    <li>item3 </li>
    <li>item4 </li>
    <li class="odd">item5 </li>
    <li class="odd">item6</li>
    <li>item7 </li>
    <li>item8 </li>
    <li class="odd">item9 </li>
    <li class="odd">item10 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not Magento-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your if statement from

```
if($i++ %2 == 0){
```

To

```
if($i++ % 4 < 2){
```